# spring MVC LazyInitialisationException

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

we are working on springMVC java config app. I am facing a problem every time when i trying to view child object properties but getting lazyinitialisationexception no session error. this i am getting on ajax calls also. I know that eager fetching is one solution and Hibernate.initailize(child) is another. But what is the standard way to resolve this?

My entities are like this

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY_DETAILS")
public class Country implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<State> states;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 20, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void set Id(Long  id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 20, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Country() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Country(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;

    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "countryId")
    public Set<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }
    public void setUnits(Set<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }






}
```

States entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "State_DETAILS")
public class State implements  Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "State_ID", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private Long StateId;
    @Column(name = "State_NAME", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String StateName;
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Country_ID", nullable = false, //
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "Country_DETAIL_State_FK") )
    private Country countryId;
    Public Long getStateId() {
        return StateId;
    }
    public void setStateId(Long StateId) {
        this.StateId = StateId;
    }
    public String getStateName() {
        return StateName;
    }
    public void setStateName(String StateName) {
        this.StateName = StateName;
    }

    public Country getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }
    public void setCmdId(Country countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public State(Long StateId) {
        super();
        this.StateId = StateId;
    }
    public State() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }





}
```

My Controller

This is my controler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findStatesByCountry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<State> findAllStateByCountryId() {
          Country c=new Country();
          c.setId((long) 1);
         List<State> states=stateService.getStatesByCommand(c);

        return units;    
    }
```

Error I am getting is

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I want to show in view like country.state.stateId ,state.country.name e.t.c .

How to resolve this type of situation?

Eager is the not the solution i want to use

Comment: Good explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877900/spring-opensessioninviewfilter-with-transactional-annotationp

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally.OpenEMInViewFilter is the solution..I tried the following and working fine...

```
<filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have used interceptor also..

```
<mvc:interceptors> <mvc:interceptor> <mvc:mapping path="/**"/> <mvc:exclude-mapping 
        path="/resources/**"/> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor" 
        />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

it is working fine now and able to fetch associations in views.Let me know if any cons in this type of usage...

Thanx